# Passing paragraph with jQuery

Tags: jquery, ajax, cakephp

```
$.ajax({
    url: url,
    type: 'POST',
    cache: false,
    data: "param=value",
    success: function (html) {
        if (loading_div != '') {
            document.getElementById(loading_div).innerHTML = "<img src ='" + fullurl + "/img/loading.gif' />";
            document.getElementById(loading_div).style.display = 'none';
        }
        $("#" + update_div).html(html).animate({
            opacity: "9.7"
        }, "slow");
    }
});
```

This is my code. I would like to pass one paragraph to the php function by url

http://mywebsite.com/functionname/Pragraph from the text editor will come here (nearly 1000 words).

How can I pass it?

Answer (score 2):

You'll want to create an object for your data, inside of it, set a paragraphVal—or whatever—to the text in your paragraph

```
data: { paragraphVal :  $("#yourParagraphId").text()},
```

Also, the other answer has pointed out the simpler way to clear the html from an element.  Here's a simpler way to hide an element:

```
$("#loading_div").hide();
```

This can replace

```
document.getElementById(loading_div).style.display ='none';
```

Answer (score 0):

Pass it into the data parameter as an object, rather than a string of key-value pairs:

```
var paragraph = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...";
$.ajax({                
    url:  url,
    type: 'POST',
    cache: false,
    data: {"paragraphParam" : paragraph},    
    success:  function(html){ 
              if(loading_div!=''){
                document.getElementById(loading_div).innerHTML = "";
                document.getElementById(loading_div).style.display ='none';
                            }
               $("#"+update_div).html(html).animate({opacity: "9.7"}, "slow");
                        }
    });
```

By the way, since you're using JQuery, you may want to take full advantage of its other built-in functions. For example:

```
document.getElementById(loading_div).innerHTML = "";
```

and

```
$("#"+loading_div).html("");
```

...are identical.

So are:

```
document.getElementById(loading_div).style.display ='none';
```

and

```
$("#"+loading_div).css("display", "none");
```

...which is essentially the same as:

```
$("#"+loading_div).hide();
```